# How to use Chrome Push Notifications from Http site

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-messaging, web-push

How can I integrate chrome push notification (GCM) on my HTTP site. That would be great help if i could get any sample related to this? According to Google documents this is only for HTTPS sites, but is there any way to integrate push on HTTP site?.

Please help me, I am stuck here?

Comment: if the documentation states that it is only for HTTPS sites then I would assume you can only use it for HTTPS sites

Comment: But I saw many sites able to send push through HTTP, If there is a possibility, please help me

Comment: You said the documentation states the limits, I based my comment on **your** question, not on `google-cloud-messaging` documentation

Comment: Can you point to a site using http? it should not be possible since the Service Worker that receives the events only runs in https

Answer (score 2):

The Web API needs a service worker so the piece that receives the events needs to be https for sure.

I am not sure if you would be able to register via http through some iframe trickery but I would not count on it. Even if you manage to do it there are no guarantees that it will keep working since as you say the documentation says it is only for https sites.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible only with https site. But the workaround is this you will have to maintain one https domain. For Http site, you will use an iframe or Modal for getting a subscription and redirect to your https service worker. This is the only way to do this.